# Making a Shell in C

Tags: c, linux, shell

I'm trying to make a basic shell in C by parsing the input and then add the fork and exec calls that allow the shell to invoke other commands, and redirection and pipes.

The parsing was easy to do and now the text inputed is in an array of char but I'm lost on how to continue.

I know I should have something like this:
    int pid = fork();
    if ( pid == 0 ) { 
    execlp("ls", "");
    }

But I don't know how to pass an array of characters to the execlp command.

Comment: You might consider reviewing the code to [dash](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dash) and/or [rc](http://tobold.org/article/rc).

Answer (score 0):

`execlp` expects the command to run, followed by a list of arguments.  The first argument is typically the name of the program and is what will show up in a `ps` listing.  The last argument must be NULL; that tells `execlp` that the end of the argument list has been reached.

So if you wanted to call `ls -l` you would do this:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
```

EDIT:

Given that you'll be passing a variable number of arguments for each command, you're better off using `execvp` instead.  This takes the command to run and an array of strings (`char *`), the last element of which is NULL.

So if the command to run is `ls -l`, you would parse this as two strings, `ls` and `-l`.  Your array of parameters would contain `param[0] = "ls"`, `param[1] = "-l"`, and `param[2] = NULL`.  Then call:

```
execvp(param[0], param);
```

Comment: Right. So as of now in my parsing code if you typed "ls" it would input into the char array token as token[0] = 'l' and token[1]='s'. How do I put this into execlp?

Comment: @Ben You're parsing incorrectly.  Tokens should be separated by a space, so in this case you only have one token.